# Do I have to annotate React methods when using Flow?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm new to Flow and feel like this is a lot of boiler plate. Do I have to explicitly state types for React or is Flow able to infer these types automatically?

```
export class MakeCoffee extends React.Component<Props> {
  componentDidMount = (): void => {
    this.props.getCoffee(this.props.id);
  };

  render(): React.Node {
    const {sugar} = this.props;

    return (
      <PoorMilk sugar={sugar} />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to specify the type of the built in React functions like (except if you really wish to do so):

- componentDidMount
- componentWillReceiveProps
- etc..

Otherwise if you want to define a props as a function you do something like this:

```
 type Props = {
   onClickFunction: Function
 }
```

On the other hand if you want to add types to some function inside the class, you can specify the return type and the param types like this:

```
function onClickFunction(param1: string, param2: number): string {}
```

Last but not least, if you are using fat arrow functions, you can write it like this: (Additionally here you can add the type of the constant :Function)

```
const onClickFunction: Function = (param1: string, param2: number): string => {}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to annotate standard methods from `React.Component`.

By extending `React.Component`, Flow is already using the declarations in its bundled '[react.js](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/c4aa3e6744ea18606255443115e8299eb4c71e86/lib/react.js#L22-L84)' file to know what your component is doing. You can see in that file that the two methods you annotated are already done for you:

```
/**
 * Base class of ES6 React classes, modeled as a polymorphic class whose main
 * type parameters are Props and State.
 */
declare class React$Component<Props, State = void> {
  ...
  render(): React$Node;
  ...
  componentDidMount(): mixed;
  ...
}
```